# Chrome Vox not getting radio buttons

Tags: html, google-chrome, radio-button, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm testing a website for accessibility using Chrome Vox. I have 3 radio buttons, one of which is selected. I have no idea why, but Chrome Vox only reads the selected radio button, the others are ignored.

Here's an example:

```
<p>Chrome Vox test</p>

<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" tabindex="0" role="radio" aria-checked="false">
<label for="radio1" class="space">Big explosions!!</label>

<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" tabindex="0" role="radio" aria-checked="true" checked>
<label for="radio2">Free beer!!</label>

<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" tabindex="0" role="radio" aria-checked="false">
<label for="radio3">Hot girls!!</label>
```

Here's a snippet:

```html
<p>Chrome Vox test</p>

<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" tabindex="0" role="radio" aria-checked="false">
<label for="radio1" class="space">Big explosions!!</label>
    
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" tabindex="0" role="radio" aria-checked="true" checked>
<label for="radio2">Free beer!!</label>

<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" tabindex="0" role="radio" aria-checked="false">
<label for="radio3">Hot girls!!</label>
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cthulhu/ma37btye/1/).

Any ideas of why Chrome Vox ignores the other radio buttons? What can I do to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Remove the tabindex, the role and the aria-checked attributes and try again

Comment: I tried that already, it doesn't solve the problem, the problem maintains.

Comment: Looks like a ChromeVox bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is "default" browser behavior. When navigating with `tab` one can enter the radio button group and, once inside the group, navigation through the different options is performed using the arrow keys. For me doesn't seem very obvious, but I'll try to understand if this is the expected behavior for a real accessibility user.

So, this is actually not a problem with the code or Chrome Vox, but it is the way browsers are supposed to work.

Comment: That's exactly correct and is how radio groups have behaved for decades.  You tab to the group then use the arrow keys to navigate within the group.  You can see this spec'ed out in the authoring practices - http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#radiobutton